# Visual Studio display glitching out

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, plugins, visual-glitch

I'm having a persistent problem with my VS2010.  After working for a while, the display will start to glitch out.  The code all shows as black-on-black (I use a dark background because it's easier on the eyes, but even when I switched to the default, it just makes the text white-on-white instead.)  All tooltip hovers appear in the upper-left corner of the screen instead of where they're supposed to.  If you select text, the code that gets selected is nowhere near where you clicked the mouse.  (Not that you can read the text anyhow since it's the same color as the background.)  And none of the dockable panels will appear or if they do they're all glitched out as well.  The only solution seems to be closing the program and restarting it.  I've been using this copy of VS2010 for years without issue, and my other projects don't seem to have any problems.  This one is C#, uses a lot of Windows Forms (not WPF), has some customized Controls, but otherwise isn't all that unusual.  I have the following extensions:

- CodeMaid
- CSharpIntellisensePresenter
- InheritanceMargin
- ProductivityPowerTools
- Tunnel Vision Labs Output Window Services
- WatermarkTextBox Control

Some of these are recently installed so they may be the culprits.  Has anyone had any display problems with any of these extensions?  I can live without most of them, but I'm not sure if it'll make a difference.  There's no easy way to test it either, as the glitch only shows up every couple of hours or so.

Comment: Try running in "safe mode" (devenv /SafeMode) for a day without any extensions enabled and see if it happens again?

Comment: Next time it glitches I'll try that.  I'm not sure what'll happen without some of those extensions.  WatermarkTextBox Control, in particular adds a control to the toolbox which I'm using in several of the forms.  Hopefully removing the extension won't make all of those break...